# Is there a good way to add FutureLocal.java to custom Future.java extending CompletableFuture? (example code below)

Tags: java, completable-future

I have the following code which was kind of close except when I call super.thenCompose and it returns a CompletableFuture instead of my Custom Future.java which is kind of critical.  I am trying to copy twitter's scala futures that

1. Be able to add cancellation chaining like twitter scala's futures
2. can have a request context flow through the thenApply and thenCompose chains to fix MDC in slf4j (much like a ThreadLocal but it is re-applied just before each lambda is run as seen in the code below)

   public class Future extends CompletableFuture {

   ```
   @Override
   public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenApply(Function<? super T, ? extends U> fn) {
       Map<String, Object> state = FutureLocal.fetchState();
       MyFunction f = new MyFunction(state, fn);       

       return super.thenApply(f);
   }

   @Override
   public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenCompose(Function<? super T, ? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn) {
       Map<String, Object> state = FutureLocal.fetchState();
       MyFunction f = new MyFunction(state, fn);

       return super.thenCompose(f);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
   private class MyFunction implements Function {

       private Map<String, Object> state;
       private Function fn;

       public MyFunction(Map<String, Object> state, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Function fn) {
           this.state = state;
           this.fn = fn;

       }

       @Override
       public Object apply(Object t) {

           try {
               FutureLocal.restoreState(state);

               return fn.apply(t);

           } finally {
               FutureLocal.restoreState(null);
           }


       }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean complete(T value) {
       return super.complete(value);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean completeExceptionally(Throwable ex) {
       return super.completeExceptionally(ex);
   }
   ```

   }

Here is some code I use to run that code but logging the "test" in the map starts failing on the 3rd remote call meaning slf4j MDC will break down.

```
public class TestCustomFutures {

    private Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    @Test
    public void testFutureContext() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

        FutureLocal.put("test", 100);

        CompletableFuture<Integer> f = myRemoteCall(4)
            .thenCompose(s -> myRemoteCall(3))
            .thenCompose(s -> myRemoteCall(2));

        f.get();
    }

    private Future<Integer> myRemoteCall(int i) {
        System.out.println("result="+i+" map="+FutureLocal.get("test")+" thread="+Thread.currentThread().getName());

        Future<Integer> f = new Future<Integer>();

        exec.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    f.completeExceptionally(e);
                }

                f.complete(i);
            }
        });

        return f;
    }
}
```

The output then is this

```
result=4 map=100 thread=main
result=3 map=100 thread=pool-1-thread-1
result=2 map=null thread=pool-1-thread-2
```

notice that last value we do not want to be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhh, I was missing one simple thing BECAUSE I was in jdk8.  In jdk11 however, you can override this...

```
@Override
public <U> CompletableFuture<U> newIncompleteFuture() {
    return new Future<U>();
}
```

In jdk8, for some reason, this would not compile and it would not invoke this :(.  Crap, I didn't want to upgrade to 11 yet as some usages are stilll on jdk8 :(.